# Can't remove "C:\fakepath\" with javascript replace and regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've been stuck for some time with this problem. Here's a part of the code in question:

```
jQuery(':file').change(function() {
    var path = jQuery(this).val();
    var filename = path.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/, '');
jQuery(this).parent().find('.placetoshowfilename').html(filename);
});
```

I can get a file path fine, but when i try to remove the "C:\fakepath\" part from it with regex i get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /" error. Regex should be correct, isn't it? Can you tell me, what i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

(It's WP, that's why jQuery is in a safe mode.)

edit: Well, it worked in JSFiddle and it suddenly started to work on my page as well. But i still have no clue what was the culprit.

Comment: *"with jQuery's replace and regex'* jQuery doesn't have `replace` or regular expressions. JavaScript does.

Comment: .replace(/^C:\\fakepath\\/i, '')); Canu try with this

Comment: [What you have works](https://jsfiddle.net/3bs8fd2u/), provided you really get `C:\fakepath\file.txt` from the input. [This one works too](https://jsfiddle.net/aqoLtzjb/1/), using a file input.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Was about to post the same.  Even if that isn't the input, the code as posted shouldn't throw that error.

Comment: Side note: You'd want `.text(filename)`, not `.html(filename)`. But that's not what's wrong (because there *isn't* anything wrong in the question).

Comment: I get the error you report when the regexp is /C:\fakepath\/. With /C:\\fakepath\\/ I get a result of: C:akepath.

Comment: You're absolutely correct about js/jQuery, i edited topic and tags. I use html(filename) because i added some html-tags there later. Anyway, it works now, thank you for your input!

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> var filename = path.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/, '');
> ```

Use extracting a name instead of removing the path:

```
var filename = path.match(/[^\\/]*$/)[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

This Worked In my case

```
  $("#UploadPoFiles").change(function () {
        $("#uploader3").val(this.files && this.files.length ?
              this.files[0].name : this.value.replace(/^C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''));
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than grabbing the **entire path** as a string and then seeking to replace `C:\fakepath\` within that string, you can simply grab the **filename** *without* the path prefix:

```
const myFileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
const myFileName = myFileInput.files[0].name;
```

Answer (score -1):

What you have works in my browser console. So I can only assume that your js file might be preprocessed by some tool. Since the potential problem is related to the `/` symbol, avoiding using it may help. `.replace()` method takes a string as well. So try this:

```
path.replace('C:\\fakepath\\', '');
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe you're right as it worked in JSFiddle and it suddenly started to work on my page as well.